# Java creating classes for xml marshalling

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

Hello i'm trying to create Java classes that can marshall the following xml

```xml
<ns1:container name="test">
    <ns1:subContainer type="String">
        <ns1:value>hello_world</ns1:value>
    </ns1:subContainer>
</ns1:container>
```

example 2

```xml
<ns1:container name="test2">
    <ns1:subContainer type="String">
        <ns1:value>hello_world2</ns1:value>
    </ns1:subContainer>
</ns1:container>
```

Now the name attribute is different on these 2 examples. What I would like to do is to use the same java class for both xmls but be able to change the value of the name attribute.

So far i've created

```java
public class Container {
    @XmlAttribute(name="test")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="subContainer", namespace = "ns1")
    private SubContainer subContainer;

    public Container() {
    }

    public Container(String value, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subContainer = new SubContainer("String", value);
    }
}
```

and this works for the first example. however, `@XmlAttribute(name="test")` needs a constant so how can i reuse this class for example 2? Or is there a better way to dynamically change the attribute?

Comment: It should be `@XmlAttribute(name="name")`, because in the annotation of the class you put the name of the attribute (which is `name`), not its value (that is `test`).

Comment: wait, the name of the attribute is name and its value is test

so name="value" should be correct since i want to be able to change the value of the attribute name

Comment: The annotation that you're using on the property `private String name` is telling JAXB that your XML will contain an attribute called `test` that contains whatever value is after the `=` sign. Which is not what you want. What you want is that the attribute is called `name` and will contain whatever value is after the `=` sign (that may be `test` or `test2`